# Dynamic query parameters for the authorization request

Tags: apache, authentication, openid, mod-auth-openidc

Hello I want to configure `apache2` server to redirect unauthorized user to my provider login page such as `google`, `gluu` and etc.. I'm using `mod_auth_openidc` and the below code snippet my `default-ssl.conf` file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:8443>
        OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://<my_provider>/.well-known/openid-configuration
        OIDCClientID <client_code>
        OIDCClientSecret <client_secret>
        OIDCRedirectURI https://<my_site>:8443/cgi-bin/
        #OIDCAuthRequestParams acr_values=auth_request_params
        OIDCResponseType code
        OIDCScope "openid profile email"
        OIDCSSLValidateServer Off
        OIDCCryptoPassphrase 123456
        OIDCPassClaimsAs environment
        OIDCClaimPrefix USERINFO_
        OIDCPassIDTokenAs payload
        <Location "/">
            Require valid-user
            AuthType openid-connect
        </Location>


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now with this configuration eveything is ok. When I enter my site apache redirect me to the OP login page. I have 3 kind of authentication mechanism  and my provider decided which login page must be loading depend on `acr_values` and for display language from `ui_locales` param from the request. To do this I should pass this params to auth requset url. But with `mod_auth_openidc` I could not do. I can set `OIDCAuthRequestParams` statically but this not solve my problem because the login mechanism and language depend on user's choice.

I read [this documentation](https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/wiki#13-how-can-i-add-custom-parameters-to-the-authorization-request) and use the below link. But it does not work. I don't know may be I misunderstand something.

> [my_site]?target_link_uri=[my_site/mypage.html]&iss=[my_provider]&auth_request_params=[urlencoded-query-string]

Is that wrong? How can I pass dynamic `acr_values` and `ui_locales` so that apache generate the auth request with these query parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly trigger an authentication request indeed by redirecting the the `OIDCRedirectURI` and provide the `auth_request_params` parameters together with `target_link_uri` and `iss`. E.g.

```
https://<my_site>:8443/cgi-bin/?target_link_uri=[my_site/mypage.html]&iss=[my_provider]&auth_request_params=acr_values%3Dsome_acr%26ui_locales%3Den
```

When you're using it with a single provider ou do need to use a relatively recent version of mod_auth_openidc >= 2.3.0